# How can I remove an oily stain from raw wood before painting?

Tags: painting, exterior, porch

I need to paint my front porch, but there is a small stain that appears to be oil, grease, or a similar substance. (Water beads on it, despite there being no paint or finish.) Here's the stain in context:

[image]

And here is a tight zoom on just the stain itself:
[image]

How does this affect the prep or the painting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mix a box of baking soda or sawdust with mineral spirits or isopropyl alcohol to the consistency of toothpaste and rub it in with a soft brush, leave for an hour and then hose off.   Preheating the wood with a hair drier or as if in the sun to allow oil to flow easier , then reapply ,  If the stain persists repeat.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an oil/floor dry product (clay or diatomaceous earth) for a day or two. Standard cat litter would also work in a pinch. This should pull most of it out.

You'll want to prime the raw wood anyway, so use a good quality bonding primer to ensure good adhesion.

Comment: Grinding and pulverizing the kitty litter into the stain with a twist of your boot will help get the particles down to maximize surface contact.